# How can I use the Azure pipelines task library to make an http request?

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

See the library here https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/master/node/docs/azure-pipelines-task-lib.md

I'm using this to create a minimal release task, which I can succesfully call into.
In this task, I call `const myUrl: string = tl.getEndpointUrl('myEndpoint', true);`
How can I then make a web request using this url?

I've tried `import * as rm from 'typed-rest-client/RestClient';` and using the rest client, but when I run this on the Azure devops build agent, I get the output:

> ##[error]Unhandled: Cannot find module 'typed-rest-client/RestClient'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to ensure `npm install typed-rest-client --save` was run from within the same folder as my `.ts` file was located in to ensure it was packaged as part of the `node_modules` that I uploaded.

Comment: Absolutely, I had tried and SO indicated I needed to wait up to 48 hours to mark my own answer as accepted. Thanks for the reminder.